# Bottom of dishwasher leaking when not running

Tags: plumbing, leak, dishwasher

I just moved into a house and was trying to adjust the dishwasher height when I noticed the bottom of the dishwasher is leaking when I'm not even using it. Here is the leaking part circled in red:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTn4z.jpg
[image]

I've noticed that if I turn the shut off the water supply it does stop leaking so I assume it's not some buildup of water from a previous run that's leaking.

Because of this I'm assuming this is the water inlet hose and it's leaking but it's unclear to me what I can do about this. Specifically, is it because the dishwasher isn't level and water leaks as a result for some reason? Or is it just the connection is loose or broken? Do I need a new dishwasher?

Comment: what's that black hose of the back of the brass bit, is that where the water supply connects?

Comment: It's kinda hard to tell with this photo, but the hose connected to the leaking part is silver. I do believe it's the water supply line because of the fact that the leaking stops when I shut off the water valve but otherwise I don't know.

Comment: For sure it is. Zooming in on the picture it is clearly a braided water hose.

Comment: yes I see it now a: hose with braided stainless-steel covering.

Comment: A dishwasher slightly unlevel wouldn't leak, it's clearly a hose connection issue.  Determine whether it's the brass fitting or the braided line and tighten it. An over-tightened brass fitting can also crack and lead to a leak as well.  To tighten the brass fitting, disconnect the braided line (shut off your water first) and then tighten it. If it already feels tight, remove it and add some plumbers tape around the threads, it may not have been wrapped around low enough for the fitting.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Best case scenario is the brass bit just needs a bit more Teflon tape, and no parts are required. However, you need to figure out whether it is from the dishwasher to the brass L adapter, or the L adapter to the hose. If it is between the dishwasher and the L adapter, you have no choice but to take everything apart, because you can't possibly re-apply the Teflon tape otherwise.

If you need to replace anything, you may consider just outright skipping that L adapter and attach a hose directly to the dishwasher.  You should have enough floor clearance to do that.

[image]

Comment: tape will fix it if it's actiually on straight. the brass piece looks like it might be cross-threaded. (on crooked)  another option would be a hose that ends in a right-angle hose union

Comment: The adapter is probably pipe thread not a compression fitting and the source of the leak I would go with eliminating the adapter. +